# HTTP live streaming crashing on iOS 4.2, doesn't crash on 4.3

Tags: iphone, ipad, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

We have a HTTP live streaming app for ipad. There are a couple of streams we have which work fine on any OS. However, one of the streams just crashes on iOS 4.2 and on iOS 4.3, although I do not get a crash, the stream doesn't play. I get a playback ended message from the player.

I am using MPMoviePlayerController for the player. There have been some changes to it from iOS 4.2 to 4.3. But am not sure what causes the player to crash on iOS 4.2 and not crash on iOS 4.3.

Any ideas?

When I run the app and check the console in iPhone configuration utility, it says "exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault"

Comment: Using Xcode 4? Make sure you're using Xcode 4.0.1.

Comment: I am on XCode 3.2.6 and I am building my binary with iOS 4.3 GM and target set to iOS 3.2 and I am running the app on the device

Comment: Ah. Not the problem I'm thinking of, then. Hopefully someone else can help. :)

Comment: Sounds like a faulty stream. Tried some validators on those?

Comment: Yups..finally checked the m3u8 files and it turns out the m3u8 file was having incorrect key value that was being used for stream encoding. Hopefully the people responsible for the streams will correct that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I bet it is a CODEC issue.

The iOS devices are very particular in how the video is encoded.  This in theory can vary slightly from version to version, device to device, video to video.  Ensure you are encoding the video as h264 Baseline Profile 3.0 with AAC audio.

Comment: The m3u8 files contained incorrect external key value that was being used for encoding the segments and were appearing at wrong places. Thanks.